How to dynamically import SCSS files using React in production?
Some background:
I'm building my first large-scale React app, and I've decided to use SASS + Bootstrap alongside it. Because of the way my project is set up, I'm having trouble dynamically changing the color scheme of the page. My first thought was to try to require the file on-the-fly, like in the code below.
However, this only works in my development server, not in my production build. Is there a better way I could go about this?
index.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles/critical.scss";

import { getLocalValue, setLocalValue, removeLocalValue } from "./utils/settings.js";

import Home from "./home/home";
import Chat from "./chat/chat";

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  // Load the current theme from LocalStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    if (getLocalValue("theme")) setTheme(getLocalValue("theme"));
    setLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  // Apply the theme by dynamically requiring it
  useEffect(() => {
    require(`./styles/${theme}.scss`);
  }, [theme])

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {!loaded ? (
        <div className="loading-container">
          <div className="loading">
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> }></Route>
          <Route path="/chat" element={ <Chat /> }></Route>
        </Routes>
      )}
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <App />
)

light.scss (partial)
$primary:   #4077AA;
$secondary: #D0D0D0;
$light:     #F0F0F0;
$dark:      #333333;
$success:   #4CAF50;
$danger:    #FF6F61;

$theme-colors: (
  primary:   $primary,
  secondary: $secondary,
  light:     $light,
  dark:      $dark,
  success:   $success,
  danger:    $danger
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";


#root {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

Some notes:
I've taken several steps towards debugging over the last several days, but to no avail. These include:

Using standard CSS variables, rather than SASS variables (Bootstrap's themes wouldn't change, and those are closely integrated with my site in className attributes)
Changing the SASS variables through JS (not possible because they're precompiled)
Dynamically requiring / importing the SCSS file (doesn't work in production, and, oddly enough, I get a syntax error if I use import <file>, but not when I use import(<file>).

I've also spent a countless number of hours scouring the internet for a solution that will modify Bootstrap's themes as well, but I haven't found a solution.
My question:
Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Why using CSS variables didn't work exactly? https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/css-custom-properties-vs-sass-variables

@Arkellys I might've done something wrong, but Bootstrap was throwing an error about --[variable name] is not a valid color, or something to that effect.

Probably the best way would be to first make sure that the scss files are compiled into css. Then make sure they are hosted with your project or on a CDN. You can do this pretty easily with webpack if you didn't use CRA or if you eject your app. Just make sure that your css files are not put in the same bundle as your other files.
You can dynamically import stylesheets in a variety of ways. For example, you can return a <link rel="stylesheet" href={cssSource}> on a component where cssSource is a string that points to your hosted css file. Of course there are other ways too, but they all will use similar methods of adding a link stylesheet.
See: Dynamically load a stylesheet with React
